# как лучше организовать бесперебойную работу формы?

Tags: mysql

есть система обработки заявок, есть форма для неё. при создании заявки выдаётся её id (autoincrement). может случиться так, что форма будет работать, а система будет не доступна, надо сделать так что бы со стороны выглядело будто всё работает. система и форма на разных серверах

как лучше организовать сохранение данных с возможностью выдать будущий идентификатор в системе которая не доступна?

я думал о следующем: сохранение данных json в локальной базе сервера с формой с резервацией id для заявок которые точно не заняты, но механизм MySQL (5.5.6) не даёт создавать произвольные id (счётчик autoincrement сразу меняется на максимальный+1), т.е. при создании этих заявок в системе я сразу "ломаю" autoincrement. можно ли это как то обойти?

или есть какие нибудь ещё варианты?

Comment: Каким-то образом использовать UUID, например

Comment: Вы не можете прогнозировать ID в виде автоинкремента в подобной системе, лучше используйте UUID и сортировку по дате внесения заявки.

Comment: `UUID представляет собой 16-байтный (128-битный) номер`, проблема в том что в форме надо уже выдать какой то номер, у меня номера в виде 6ти цифр, получается мне придётся показать вместо 6ти 16 символов и никак иначе?

Comment: @Maximmka с шестью цифрами неизбежно будут коллизии, или не показывайте его до успешной связи с системой и с MySQL, или выкручивайтесь как-то иначе

Comment: Генерируйте и сохраняйте ID только на форме, а на сервере только записывайте их

Comment: Как вариант можно завести отдельный (микро)сервис, который будет заниматься только выдачей id (разруливая все коллизии) и ничем больше, если возможно организовать его постоянную доступность. А уже потом помещать выданный id в MySQL без всяких автоинкрементов

Comment: нет возможности вынести генерацию id из системы.
есть такая идея: если система не доступна, то приписывать к данным дополнительное поле содержащее произвольный идентификатор с префиксом, в систему всё добавится как обычно, при поиске по префиксу будет понятно как именно нужно искать - в штатном режиме или в доп полях. как такая идея?

Comment: @Maximmka Норм идея, вот вы и ответили на свой вопрос :) Еще как вариант выдавать с префиксом, что это локальный id (как и в вашем варианте), а на сервере с формой сохранять отдельно, хоть в MySQL, хоть в каком нибудь Redis на какой локальный id какой серверный в итоге был выдан

Answer (score 0):

спасибо всем прокоментировавшим.

как сделал:

при недоступности системы данные сохраняются в локальную бд в формате json, добавляется дополнительное поле которое содержит произвольный идентификатор с префиксом. по крону (на стороне системы обращений) каждый день проверяется наличие сохранённых записей на сервере с формой.

поиск будет осуществляться либо по стандартному идентификатору, либо по полю, в зависимости от наличия префикса в запрашиваемом идентификаторе.